# Cannot infer correct types in selectIds from getSelectors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple redux store setup with `createEntityAdapter`. The initial state contains and entity, ids, status, error setup as such

```
const carouselEventAdapter = createEntityAdapter<CarouselEventStateInterface>()

const initialState = carouselEventAdapter.getInitialState({
  entities: { //some data here },
  ids: [1,2],
  status: 'idle',
  error: null,
})

const carouselEventSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'carouselEvent',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {},
})

export const {
  selectIds,
  selectById,
} = carouselEventAdapter.getSelectors<RootState>( state => state.carouselEvent)

// export const {} = carouselEventSlice.actions

export default carouselEventSlice.reducer
```

When I try to call the selectIds function, it shows me the type as `EntityId[]` while I want `number[]` as the type for `eventids`

```
const eventids = useSelector(selectIds)
```

Could someone correct me on my types because I've tried to find answers to this everywhere and no luck

Answer (score 0):

By including `id: [1,2]` in your initial state, the state type for the slice becomes `ids: number[]`.  But the entity adapter just uses `EntityId`.

As a workaround, you can select the `ids` from the state directly without using `getSelectors`

```
const useSelector = createSelectorHook<RootState>();

const eventIds = useSelector(state => state.carouselEvent.ids );
```

This gets the type `EntityId[] & number[]` which is just `number[]`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkpDW)

Now you've got me wondering how hard it would be for the redux-toolkit types to support a generic `<I extends EntityId = EntityId>` here.